# Sanity check: MathJax rendering?

Tags: bug, mathjax

Okay: I received a Windows 8 update about 12 hours ago (automatically- forced shutdown and updated, so others may have updated earlier), and since then, MathJax is rendering differently (less readable, from my perspective, fainter type, and certainly not as "pretty" as previously).

Has anyone else encountered this with the most recent Windows 8 Update? Nothing else has changed, I'm still using FireFox.

I'll need to tag this, so will use the "bug" tag, though it may only be "my bug"!

Comment: I don't think you can blame SE for this... recheck your MathJax configuration in Firefox (after updating it).

Comment: @vonbrand I really didn't think it was an SE issue, but more about how to correct "my issue"...and, I have to admit, I don't know how to check MathJax configuration in Firefox! :-Z

Comment: Is any of the other text rendering differently, or is it only MathJax? Also, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ I think it's only MathJax rendering differently, but there does seem to be a slight change to the consistency of some of the other text on the site, but barely noticeable. I'll see about posting a screenshot...

Comment: Can someone remind me how to take a screen shot? (yes, there are some things I should know by now!)

Comment: Pint screen key! Right above insert, on my keyboard. That saves a screenshot to clipboard, then you can open up paint to crop the area, save it, then upload it. http://ww2.justanswer.com/uploads/jhannell/2010-05-02_095651_KeyboardPrintscreenKey.jpg

Comment: Did the update perhaps include the STIX fonts, which you didn't have installed before?  MathJax will use locally installed STIX fonts in preference to its web-based fonts, so that might account for the difference you are seeing.  Otherwise, are there any settings for font smoothing or antialiasing in Windows 8? (I haven't used it myself)  In older versions of Windows, you had to activate that by hand.  Perhaps your settings were reset by the update?

Comment: Thanks, @Davide, I think you may have nailed it! The STIX fonts...I'll look into it further. I'll also check into adjusting the settings for font smoothing or antialiasing...which is desperately needed, given what I'm seeing now!

Comment: @amWhy, If you prefer the MathJax web fonts, you can install them locally as well (they will be used in preference to local STIX fonts).  They are available at [the MathJax GitHub site](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/tree/master/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf).  You will need all but the last two.